# Find matching elements in array and do something for each match

Tags: lodash

I'm a little overwhelmed by all the functions available to me in Lodash, so I hope someone can point me to the one I'm sure exists which will do the following for me. I want to be able to pass an array and a search condition, and have it loop through all the matched items, allowing me to run a function for each. What I have at the moment is something akin to this:

```
_.each(myArray, (item) => {
    if (item.field=="whatever") {
      console.log("Matched by "+item.name);
    }
});
```

This works fine, of course. It's just that I'm sure Lodash has a way for me to move the `item.field=="whatever"` into the function arguments somehow, and I'd prefer to go with the more idiomatic Lodash way if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's just that I'm sure Lodash has a way for me to move the `item.field == "whatever"` into the function arguments somehow

If you want to find all the matching items in an array based on the arguments you pass in, then you could use the [`_.filter` method](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), which can use the [`_.matches` shorthand](https://lodash.com/docs#matches) internally:

```
_.filter(myArray, { field: 'whatever' });
```

However, you would still need to loop over the items if you want to do something for each match:

```
_.each(_.filter(myArray, { field: 'whatever' }), item => {
  console.log("Matched by " + item.name);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want a different way of writing this, you can wrap the filtered items with the [lodash object wrapper, `_()`](https://lodash.com/docs#lodash), which essentially enables chaining, thereby allowing you to chain the `_.each()` method:

```
_(_.filter(myArray, { field: 'whatever' })).each(item => {
  console.log("Matched by " + item.name);
});
```

Or a more readable version:

```
var matchedItems = _.filter(myArray, { field: 'whatever' });
_(matchedItems).each(item => {
  console.log("Matched by " + item.name);
});
```

Personally, I would probably just keep what you originally wrote since it's short, readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: Happy to know that I've not missed anything! I'm not familiar with the syntax you have there: `_(matchedItems).each(item => {`. I would have written it as `_.each(matchedItems,item => {`. What's the difference?

Comment: @JohnMoore - They both do the same thing, it's just an alternative way of writing it. [`_()` is the lodash object wrapper](https://lodash.com/docs#lodash) that will convert the collection into a lodash object, which will allow you to chain other lodash methods. For example, the `_.filter()` method returns a plain array, and by wrapping it `_(_.filter())`, you can then chain another lodash methods like `_(_.filter()).each()`.